# Date check started failing

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Date check in a MS Access DB I built that has been fine for months but today is throwing out constant positives regardless of input. I've checked the outputs and they are displaying the correct week/year every time but the check is failing.
It's like overnight it has just decided to read the dates differently.

```
If Not IsNull(Raised_For) Then
  If Not Format(Me.Raised_For, "WW/YYYY", vbMonday) > Format(Date, "WW/YYYY", vbMonday) Then
  MsgBox "You must enter a date beyond the current week", vbOKOnly, "Past Date"
  Cancel = True
 End If
End If
```

Example of the check  `10/2018 > 9/2018`
comes out as `False`.

I'm really stumped on why this has started happening today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple:

Since you're comparing strings, you're doing a lexical comparison. Since the first letter of your first string, 1, is less than the first letter of your second string, 9, the comparison returns false.

Use `DateDiff` to compare dates:

```
If DateDiff("ww",  Date(), Me.Raised_For, vbMonday) > 0 Then
   'Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed. Self taught and I get by but there is many rookie mistakes I find I make still

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Erik von Asmuth, you are comparing strings, although the `Format()` part of the code. To compare the dates, try to convert the value to date and check it:

```
If Not Cdate(Me.Raised_For) > CDate(Date) Then
```

This should be enough. Consider an error catcher, to help you if `Me.Raised_For` is not a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Compare using *DateDiff*:

```
If Not IsNull(Me!Raised_For) Then
    If DateDiff("ww", Me.Raised_For, Date, vbMonday) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a date beyond the current week", vbOKOnly, "Past Date"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```